# Robust standard error estimation for the Hausman-Taylor estimator using plm() and vcovHC()

Tags: r, plm

Suppose I compute the Hausman-Taylor estimator using the **plm** command with the option: ***model= "ht"***. Using the result I like to obtain a robust variance-covariance matrix to make inference fully robust. For this purpose the **vcovHC()** command (part of the plm package) is used. Here is a minimal example:

```
data("Wages", package = "plm")
ht <- plm(lwage ~ wks + south + smsa + married + exp + I(exp^2) +
        bluecol + ind + union + sex + black + ed | 
        sex + black + bluecol + south + smsa + ind,
      data = Wages, model = "ht", index = 595)

vcvHT <- vcovHC(ht,method="arellano")
Error in vcovHC.plm(ht, method = "arellano") : 
Model has to be either random, within or pooling model
```

Technically, as the error message indicates, vcovHC() is unable to compute the VCV matrix since it does not support models of the type computed by **plm(...,model="ht")**

My question is this:

Why doesn't **vcovHC()** support the Hausman-Taylor model? Is it because standard error based on a (cluster) robust VCV matrix shouldn't be used for theoretical reasons (inconsistent etc.), or is it simply not implemented but save to use (if programmed by hand)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not implemented (yet); but as HT is a special kind of IV, it should in principle be possible to compute an HC covariance. I will get around to doing it sometime. A production version requires a lot of interface work and consideration of all possible cases; but an ad-hoc function might be relatively easy to write, based on components from the model object.