# IV Estimation with Cluster Robust Standard Errors using the plm package in R

Tags: r, plm

I'm using the plm package for panel data to do instrumental variable estimation. However, it seems that calculating cluster robust standard errors by using the vcovHC() function is not supported. 
More specifically, when I use the vcovHC() function, the following error message is displayed:

> Error in vcovG.plm(x, type = type, cluster = cluster, l = 0, inner = >inner,  : 
>    Method not available for IV

Example:

```
data("Wages", package = "plm")
IV <- plm(lwage ~ south + exp | wks + south,
      data = Wages, model = "pooling", index = 595)

vcvIV <- vcovHC(IV)
```

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869582/robust-standard-error-estimation-for-the-hausman-taylor-estimator-using-plm-an), someone worked on a fix two years ago. Is there any progress on the issue? I know that the packages "lfe" and "ivpack" allow to compute cluster robust standard errors for IV estimation but none of them allows for random effects/intercepts.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to wait until it is implemented...you can track the development version of plm here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=406

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are you currently planning to implement it any time soon?

Comment: The official CRAN release (1.6-4) of plm now has that incorporated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it's not implemented. However, you can use [Schrimpf's clustered errors function](https://bitbucket.org/paulschrimpf/production-estimation/src/b9ca566f81c0d220317ff993d3dc8d6448de227a/clusterFunctions.R?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) which is applied directly to a object of the `plm` class. 
Using your example:

```
library (plm)

data("Wages", package = "plm")

IV <- plm(lwage ~ south + exp | wks + south, data = Wages, model = "pooling", index = 595)

Wages$id <- rep(1:595, each = 7)        

cl.plm(Wages, IV, Wages$id)
```

Where I'm using `Wages$id`as the panel first dimension around which clusters will be formed. You may want to compare these results with the obtained in other software. Anyway, the code is simple allowing some tricks. The `cl.plm` function is based on Arai's [clustering notes](http://www.ne.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.216115.1426234213!/menu/standard/file/clustering1.pdf) which can help you further.

You can obtain the same result from `cl.plm` doing this in Stata:

```
ivregress 2sls lwage south (exp = wks), vce(cluster id) small
```

Or for the within model:

```
xtset id time, generic

xtivreg2 lwage south (exp = wks), fe small cluster(id)
```

Note however I used the small sample formulation in Stata, which is not big deal. More about this [here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/wp545.pdf). Anyway, `cl.plm` properly deals with the `plm` class object.

For sake of completeness: as suggested by @Helix123, you can use the development version (1.6-1) of `plm` package and proceed as you did in tour question.

Comment: It's correct @Helix123, As you can see in the reference [here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/wp545.pdf), [here](http://econweb.umd.edu/~sarzosa/teach/2/Disc2_Cluster_handout.pdf) or through lots of lectures about this in Google, the formulation for IV is not different from the standard. I guess the `vcovHC` just cannot properly handle multipart formulas of the `Formula` class.

Comment: Great! I checked with plm development version 1.6-1 and plm's `vcovHC` and `cl.plm` gives the same results except for the degrees of freedom adjustment performed in `cl.plm` (multiplies vcov by `(M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))`) which can also be performed by `vcovHC(..., type="sss")`.

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: The official CRAN release (1.6-4) of plm now has that incorporated.